# Java ME Dynamic UI Toolkit

Tags: user-interface, java-me, toolkit

Is there a UI toolkit for Java ME that I can use to generate UI elements on the fly, based on, for example, JSON or XML that I send to the device by way of a web service pull?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple UI frameworks [available](http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/component/content/article/44/73.html) for Java-me application. But i suggest [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/) framework is good. LWUIT offers advanced UI capabilities and a clean API that is inspired by Swing. You can develop your own theme and animated screens by using [LWUIT ResourceEdit](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/p/installing-latest-and-greatest-resource.html). For more info see this [LWUIT blog](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/).

You can download latest LWUIT from this [repository](http://java.net/projects/lwuit) or you can use latest release of LWUIT version 1.4 [available](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/downloads/index.html). LWUIT supports Blackberry, Android and Symbian OS.

For more info see this links for your reference,

[Introduction of LWUIT](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/)

[Building theme for LWUIT](http://www.themeswiki.org/Building_themes_using_LWUIT)

Answer (score 0):

For simple applications with a minimal footprint, try [Thinlet JME](http://sourceforge.net/projects/thinlet/files/ThinletJME). For more complicated GUIs, check out [this list](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_ME_UI_Frameworks). Also consider going with HTML, mobile phone browser are getting better every day.

Note that if you want stuff like this to work in practice, you'd want a script engine also.